# PikaChoose NEXT - BACK buttons stop working

Tags: jquery

I have carousal from www.pikachoose.com It works great.
Wanted to add the mouseover selection, that swaps the main image instead of a click.

When I add : `thumbChangeEvent:'mouseover.pikachoose',`

The NEXT and BACK buttons malfunction. As well... If I turn on the animation - it too does not work.
If I remove the `thumbChangeEvent:'mouseover.pikachoose',` it works proper again.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pikachoose.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.touchwipe.min.js"></script>

                    $(document).ready(
                    function (){
                        $("#pikame").PikaChoose({
                            thumbChangeEvent:'mouseover.pikachoose',
                            carousel:true, 
                            carouselVertical:true,
                            autoPlay:true, 
                            showCaption:false, 
                            text: {previous: "", next: ""}
                        });
                    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, did you solve your problem? I am trying to disable navigation (next and prev arrows) which appears on hover, but cannot find solution, could you give me any hint?